# my passport has ink mark on the 3rd page, and i need to apply for my canadian study permit, will it be accepted by embassy or not?

Tags: passports, study, passport-stamps, air-canada, damaged-passports

[image]

my passport has an ink mark on the 3rd page, and I need to apply for my Canadian study permit, will the embassy accept it or not?

Comment: Everyone knows that a passport is a working document.  Some stray ink smudges are to be expected.